# Hide when clicked outside of multiple elements

Tags: jquery, click, element

I need to make crossbrowser styled  tags in jQuery. So instead of making clean html SELECT element tags, i use nested elements. There will be a lot of selectboxes available on page, so they should work correctly with each other.

**Edit:** Fade effects "fadeIn() / fadeOut()" should be used instead of "hide() / show()"

Introducing an example:

Instead of having **classic clean html element** of dropdown list:

```
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

**I have nested elements so i can style them properly:**

```
<div class="gui-selectbox">
  <a class="gui-selectbox-button">
    <span class="gui-btn-l"></span>
    <span class="gui-btn-c">Option 1</span>
    <span class="gui-btn-r"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="gui-selectbox-dialog">
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    <ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the code**: http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/XR4Y3/

It should work in that way:

- When i click on any element, it should close all selectboxes
- When i click on ".gui-selectbox-button", it should show ".gui-selectbox-dialog" of its parent ".gui-selectbox"
- If user clicks outside of ".gui-selectbox-button" and ".gui-selectbox-dialog", it should close every opened selectboxes

**UPDATED:**

How can i tell to function to not close parent div if current target is its child ?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/ejyRR/5/. It' a third element.

Comment: Is `href="selectbox-button"` suppose to be `class="selectbox-button"`?

Comment: I made you a working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XR4Y3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consolidate your code quite a bit.  This will do what you want.

**Example 1**

```
$('html').on('click', function() {
    $('.gui-selectbox-dialog:visible').hide();
});

$('.gui-selectbox').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.gui-selectbox-dialog:visible').hide();
    $(this).find('.gui-selectbox-dialog').show();

    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.gui-selectbox-dialog ul').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    alert('selected = ' + $(this).text());

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Qb/

**Edit**: Updated my code and demo link since I had portions using old `.click()` event method and some using the new `.on()` method.  Also added an alert on option click.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff ! Will try to adapt my code with yours one.

Comment: I updated my answer to fix some discrepancies in the code with using old and new jQuery code. Now it is all coded to support the latest 1.7.1 version using `.on()` event methods.

Comment: By the way Jeff, i need to use "fadeIn/fadeOut" effect, i tried to put .stopPropagation function before the ".fadeIn" effect, but it makes it blinking. Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: I have updated the code, how can i know if my current target is child of the same div ? meaning: determine if it's nested or not ? thanks

Comment: **@Jeff** - is there a way in jquery to tell this: 
if my nested element is opened, and i want to close it, i can do it by clicking on it's button again, so it closes. but can i associate the same functionality into outside of the opened element ? For example: I click on 3rd element, it will open, then i click on the 4th element which seats inside of currently opened one. but i can close the 4th one, by clicking outside of it, EVEN on 3rd element's content. hope i was clear

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assign the `click()` function to your body. And within this function verify which element was clicked exactly. If it is none of your "select" boxes, close the open ones. Else, open or close the one that was clicked.

Let me clarify it in some code:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {

    if (gui_currentSelectboxID != null) {
        $this = $(event.target);
        $parent = $this.parent().parent();

        //Check if the clicked item was NOT the gui-selectbox option
        if ($parent.attr('class') != 'gui-selectbox') {
            $('#' + gui_currentSelectboxID).children('.gui-selectbox-dialog').fadeOut(100);
            $('#' + gui_currentSelectboxID).children('.gui-selectbox-button').removeClass('active');
        }
    }

});
```

This should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/XR4Y3/5/

You can still optimize this by verifying if the `.parent().parent()` actually exist, because for instance the `document` won't have two parents. Other optimizations would be to use the functions you have actually declared to hide the selectboxes etc..

Comment: @aspirinemaga I adapted my code a bit and showed you a possible way to do it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XR4Y3/5/

Comment: yes that works great, but the problem is when you click on opened dialog's content, it closes, and that is not what i want. I want that opened dialog stay opened even if you click on it, which have the same parent class as button class have.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Anyway that's an easy thing to fix once you have this already..

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, **[Chris Coyer @ CSS-Tricks.com already did what you're trying to do](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/styled-popup-menu/)**.

He also provides with all the code and explanation. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, but I have no problem to do it with .hover state. I have problems with click states. And btw he uses input tag, so you can't use nested elements inside input.